# Excel formula to take out quotations

Tags: microsoft-excel

Does anyone know a way to get excel to not include quotations in a value?

I have the formula:

```
=WEBSERVICE("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/?s="&A3&"&f=p2")
```

so that I can pull the % Change in a Stock price from Yahoo finance.

It pulls the number back as "+0.15". the quotations are preventing me from throwing the `=NumberValue` formula in front of that one so that I can format the cells.

I have the same formula (just a tab bit different URL) for Change in price and it doesn't put quotations around it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5695169/657668

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `SUBSTITUTE` to find and replace text - `=SUBSTITUTE(some_text,"""","")` will replace all double quotes with nothing.  (There are four double quotes in the second parameter because you have to double them inside strings - otherwise Excel interprets it as the end of the string).  So you could use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(WEBSERVICE("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/?s="&A3&"&f=p2"),"""","")
```

Comment: Beautiful. Works great! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Found another solution that works just as well. same formula just different input for the formula.... =SUBSTITUTE(some_text,CHAR(34),"")

Answer (score 1):

Better still, unless it's a text string, use `NUMBERVALUE`.  `P2` is a number.  Here's an example:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(WEBSERVICE("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="&A2&"&f=l1"))
```