# Which versions of MSExcel support the 'WEBSERVICE' function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

Pursuant to [Excel formula to take out quotations](https://superuser.com/questions/935173/excel-formula-to-take-out-quotations) ,

I saw that it's possible to use a form of web-querying in certain versions of MSExcel. Incidentally, what I saw was:

```
=WEBSERVICE("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/?s="&A3&"&f=p2")
```

My question is which versions of MSExcel support this 'webservice' function? I am using MSExcel 2003, myself.

Comment: It is available in Excel 2013.  It can be used in versions prior to 2013 via an add-in.

Comment: Hmm. Well that's certainly good to know! Err... got a URL to where I can get the add-in for MSOffice 2003?

Comment: @Gary's Student Hmm. Well that's certainly good to know! Err... got a URL to where I can get the add-in for MSOffice 2003?